# Javascript: on click change content without duplicated content

Tags: javascript

I have simple code that changes content in a specific  element defined by **ID**.

I need to make this code work on multiple elements with the same content. That means when I have 2 similar elements with the same content, and when user clicks on one of the elements, content on the clicked element will be changed.

Is it possible to do it with vanilla Javascript?

```
function showNumber() {
  var x = document.getElementById("showNumberTop");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Text1") {
    x.innerHTML = "Text2";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Text1";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a click listener on the parent element of all those elements with similar content. Event handler function will be passed an `event` object which contains a property named `target`. This property contains the element that was clicked on.

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');

span.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerHTML === "Text1") {
    event.target.innerHTML = "Text2";
  } else {
    event.target.innerHTML = "Text1";
  }
})
```

```html
<span>Text1</span>
```

Comment: My code is there https://jsfiddle.net/e02brau7/ and not working.

Comment: It can be in span element?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target') error called.

Comment: You need to pass the `event` object: `<span onclick="showNumber(event)">Text1</span>`

Comment: Thanks you very much!